# New Sound Design Samples...Junebugs, Trams and Icemakers Oh My!

Tags: sound-design

Here's a sample of some stuff I've designed recently.  I just wanted to get more ears and speakers on these.

Mostly recorded with my Sony PCM D-50 while traveling.  Made from junebugs recorded on my front porch, the DFW Tram, icemaker on my fridge, some street traffic and buses from Nashville in there, thunder, lightbulb going bad, windscreen being rubbed on acoustic tiles in my studio, and on-and-on-and on.  Obviously a lot of processing and playing around.

Let me know what y'all think.

[BEC-Sound Design Samples 120811](http://soundcloud.com/joeedwards/bec-sound-design-samples) by [BEC Sound Design](http://soundcloud.com/joeedwards)

Answer (score 1):

Just listened on some iMac speakers, and these all sound dope! Like an ultra-long radio imaging stinger, in a good way. And you recorded all the source for this stuff yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words!  Yeah, it's all originally recorded stuff, played with some synths to get some of the stuff and simple tones with a lot of tweaking and destroying.  Lots o' layers.  There's fireworks in there and some nasty, glitchy stuff from a couple old shortwave radios.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you had limited yourself to only the samples you listed above and was wondering where all that wonderful spiky white noise was coming from. Care to share some of your favorite plugs?

Again, good stuff.

Comment: The SoundToys bundle, Waves and the Sony Oxford bundle are my favorites right now.  You?

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't thinking and had my speakers cranked... the first hit practically tore my face off!  haha.  Very nice sounds, I like the transitions.